# Perl replacing consecutive blank lines with s/^\s*$/<p>/gm

Tags: regex, perl

I am following book about regular expressions and there is example where
one wants to replace every consecutive blank line with `<p>`.

Here is the script:

```
undef $/;
$text = <>;

$text =~ s/^\s*$/<p>/gm;
```

Here is the input `A\n\n\n\nB\n` which is same as A then 3 blank lines then B.

I expect it to output `A\n<p>B\n` because `\s` contains newline and it repeats after the beginning of second line and the end of fourth line.

But the output is `A\n<p><p>\nB\n`.

Also no matter how many blank lines I put between `A` and `B` I always get the same answer.

But when input is `A\n\n\n[ ]\nB\n` ([ ] - means space character) I get kind of correct output `A\n<p>\nB\n` but still why is there `\n` after `<p>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. The trailing newline, and the two `<p>`.

### Trailing newline

`(?m:$)` matches before a newline and at the end of the string. That means the text with which you replace will necessarily be followed by a newline or the end of the string. `\n` should have been used instead of `$`.

### Two `<p>`

This problems is the result of your pattern being able to match zero characters.

```
Your string:    A␤␤␤␤B␤  
Positions:      0123456
```

Your pattern finds two matches.

- Your pattern replaces the 2 characters starts at position 2 with `<p>`.
- Your pattern replaces the 0 characters starts at position 4 with `<p>`.

Fix:

```
s/\n{2,}/\n<p>/g
```

or

```
s/\n\s*\n/\n<p>/g   # Allows whitespace between the newlines.
```

Comment: I get it, at first I thought `$` was after newline, then I thought that `^` and `$` were consumed along the way. Someone told me that `$` also can match after `\n` doesn't that work in this case ?

Comment: I tested out `(^\s*$)\n` and it also works. Is it better solution ?

Comment: Re "*Someone told me that `$` also can match after `\n`*", As I've already stated, `(?m:$)` (`$` when the `m` modifier is in effect) matches before a newline and at the end of the string. (`(?-m:$)` matches in fewer places: before a newline at the end of the string and at the end of the string.)

Comment: Re "*Is it better solution*", It's far less readable. It's very unclear what it does. In fact, it's misleading since it looks like it matches one line.